# How to include timzonefinder module while creating an exe file via pyinstaller

Tags: python, timezone, pyinstaller

I'm trying to create an GUI which, on the basis of user's choice gets the lat and long of US states from a CSV file and gets the current time in that state using `timezonefinder` and datetime module.

I understand that few states have 2 time zones, but getting only 1 time zone is fine for this project.
While I'm able to properly use the code and it functions perfectly as a python script, but when I convert it into an executable using `pyinstaller`, I get a `FileNotFound Error`.

Here is the code:

```
import pandas
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from datetime import datetime
from timezonefinder import TimezoneFinder
import pytz

def get_time(state_choosen):
    
    tf =   TimezoneFinder()
    states_data = pandas.read_csv('data/us_states.csv')
    data_list = states_data.to_dict('records')
    
    for data in data_list:
        if state_choosen == data['state']:
            longitude = data['longitude']
            latitude = data['latitude']
            t_zone = tf.timezone_at(lng=longitude, lat=latitude)    
    
            tzone = pytz.timezone(t_zone)
            current_time = datetime.now(tz=tzone).strftime("%I:%M:%S %p")
            
            return current_time
```

And here is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
  File "main.py", line 179, in city_time
    current_time = us_time.get_time(city)
  File "us_time.py", line 10, in get_time
    tf =   TimezoneFinder()
  File "timezonefinder\timezonefinder.py", line 260, in __init__
  File "timezonefinder\timezonefinder.py", line 118, in __init__
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\vaibhav\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI71562\\timezonefinder\\poly_zone_ids.bin'
```

Please suggest how can I fix this error.
or if there is a workaround by including another library that is supported by `pyinstaller`, or maybe creating an executable by something other then `pyinstaller`?

I'm but a novice right now, so please suggest the best course of action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this parameter to the command line when running pyinstaller:

`--collect-data timezonefinder`